# how can i group mysql results based on other rows?

Tags: php, mysql

so this is relating to an appointment booking site, where i have a table for order line options

the options have the details of the customer like the date and time for the booking and location

So checking for free slots i have the location ID and the date, and i need to get the available times left for that date

so i need to select rows where the booking date matches the date in question and the location ID also matches, but they are on seperate rows like follows:

```
id     orderid     option-name     option-value
1      10          date            2022-03-12
2      10          locationID      8
3*     10          time            10:30
4      11          date            2022-03-13
5      11          locationID      8
6      11          time            10:45
7      12          date            2022-03-12
8      12          locationID      8
9*     12          time            13:45
```

So in this case i would need rows 3 and 9 because i am looking for all times booked at locationID 8 on 2022-03-12

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here we have 2 queries

- one as you have asked
- a second which gives all the information for the booking.
  I would suggest that the second would be a better format for your table, which would permit using time and date data types, or even better a datetime column. This would allow use of datetime functions sur as `dateads()` and `DateDiff()`directly without conversion whether implicit or explicit.

> ```
> create table locations (
> id int,
> order_id int,
> option_name  varchar(30),   
> option_value varchar(30) );
> ```

> ```
> insert into locations values
> (1,10,'date','2022-03-12'),
> (2,10,'locationID','8'),
> (3,10,'time','10:30'),
> (4,11,'date','2022-03-13'),
> (5,11,'locationID','8'),
> (6,11,'time','10:45'),
> (7,12,'date','2022-03-12'),
> (8,12,'locationID','8'),
> (9,12,'time','13:45');
> ```

> ```
> select
> l.order_id,
> l.option_name,
> l.option_value
> from
> locations l
> join locations d
> on l.order_id = d.order_id
> where 
> l.option_name = 'locationID'
> and l.option_value = '8'
> and d.option_name ='date'
> and d.option_value = '2022-03-12';
> ```

> ```
> order_id | option_name | option_value
> -------: | :---------- | :-----------
>       10 | locationID  | 8           
>       12 | locationID  | 8
> ```

> ```
> select
> l.order_id,
> l.option_value locationID,
> d.option_value "date",
> t.option_value "time"
> from
> locations l
> join locations d
> on l.order_id = d.order_id
> join locations t 
> on l.order_id = t.order_id
> where 
> l.option_name = 'locationID'
> and l.option_value = '8'
> and d.option_name = 'date'
> and t.option_name = 'time'
> and d.option_value = '2022-03-12';
> ```

> ```
> order_id | locationID | date       | time 
> -------: | :--------- | :--------- | :----
>       10 | 8          | 2022-03-12 | 10:30
>       12 | 8          | 2022-03-12 | 13:45
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=4c0d1a00a8c6e16ec25bc5b0707ba6e1)*

Comment: Hey, your first query is not filtering the location ID, whats the best way to filter for that also?

Comment: Yes, the current structure isn't ... query friendly.  Storing appointment information as dates/times would offer much greater flexibility.